# How can I bookmark where in a mail I was reading in Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I receive some mails which are long and/or have a lot of interesting links, and I am not able to read those mails in one time. 
I can pin and/or snooze the mail to continue reading it later, but I would like to save at which page/line I was reading.
Therefore my question is:

Is there a way to put some kind of *bookmark* in the mail such that I can later on continue reading where I was?

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Comment: I agree, but this question was asked when the application (Google Inbox) existed. Furthermore, the question can be generalized; the given answer by JBalin, for example, is applicable to any e-mail application/web.

Comment: Then make the question about Gmail. "Closing" just means preventing any new answers; it doesn't mean the content is going away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native way but you could reply to yourself and delete/make bold/change color the text you've read.

Another idea is to forward the email to your Kindle using the Kindle-generated email address. Kindle apps on all platforms should remember where you stopped reading, as do services like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) and [Pocket](http://www.getpocket.com) (which also have email addresses you can forward things to).

Comment: Thanks this might not be the solution but it is a good idea. Actually in Inbox I can edit the reply without having to send/forward it, it will stay there (and in *Drafts*) until I send/remove it.

Comment: Added another idea to answer